# Unable to remove user: "user is currently logged in"

Tags: centos, users, remove

When trying to remove the user, it returns "user is currently logged in".
I already killed the user using pkill -KILL -u usernameHere and several other commands, but it does not help.

How can I remove this user?

Running CentOS 6.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

SU to the user `su - username` and run `kill -9 -1` as the user.

Exit the shell and try the `userdel -r username` again.

Or you can check for processes from the user using `lsof -u username` and kill the relevant PIDs.

Or `pkill -u username` or `pkill -u uid`

Comment: Be careful!  Using the first command above killed all my userpace daemons.  Since it is a production server I had to restart them all manually.  So it's kind of a dangerous command on a production server.  In my case it was a node hosting dozens of VPS servers so it was a major thing for me.

Answer (score 8):

Or `ps aux | grep <username>` and `kill` the processes the user is running.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried before Googling this. When I did it, I got nothing in the grep results.

Answer (score 2):

If the above steps don't help! (Assuming you are using on the runlevel 5)

You could try the following:

1. Change the runlevel to 3 (`init 3`)
2. log-in with other than deleting account to delete (root/other account)
3. `userdel -r username`

Answer (score -2):

I try the steps to del the user1

1. su user1
2. kill -9 -1
3. su
4. sudo deluser user1

Comment: I don't see anything new in this answer. And the older answers have better explanations of what they are doing.